# C++ String's "insert" function crushes app when run more than once

Tags: c++, string, insert

I have a problem with my program. When it runs line:

```
P.insert(P.find('-'), "+");
```

once everything is ok (the function did what I wanted, put plus just before minus). But when I run it again it crushes with "This application requested a Runtime to terminate in an unusual way." error.
"P" (uppercase) is of course a String var.
I use wxDev-C++ build 7.4.1.13 and don't want to change it, if you ask. System in Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit.

Please for a quick replay, as a deadline approaches.

Comment: You need to post more code. It depends on how you are using it. And I hope that `P` is not the real name of your variable!

Comment: You wouldn't like insert when it's mad. INSERT CRUSH!!!

Comment: [The line is OK, your problem is elsewhere.](http://ideone.com/bBC70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only replace to first occurrence "-".
Is this your requirement?

If not, take that

```
int start = 0;
while (true) {
  int index = P.find('-', start);
  if (index < 0) break;
  P.insert(index, '+');
  start = index + 2;
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks for this code. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe second time there is no '-', so find return -1, and then you try to insert into position -1. So check the return value of find

```
int index = P.find('-');
if (index != -1)
    P.insert(index, '+');
```

And I also agree with *Dennis* comment..

Comment: You was absolutely right - that was the cause - thank you A LOT!